# invalid 'row.names' length, in factor analysis

Tags: r

I'm trying to do factor analysis with SPSS data in Rstudio.

## raw SPSS data

this is the structure of my data;

```
> jes2 <- haven::read_sav("jes2p.sav")
> head(jes2[1:4, 1:7])
# A tibble: 4 x 7
# The original data is very big and contains 7 panel data and 2805 variables
  BRANCH SAMPOINT CASEID    REGION   CITYSIZE        DISTID     PREFECTR
   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl+lbl>  <dbl+lbl>     <dbl+lbl>    <dbl+lbl>
1      0        0      0 3 [KANTO] 5 [+20MAN] 27 [SAITAMA1] 11 [SAITAMA]
2      0        0      1 3 [KANTO] 5 [+20MAN] 27 [SAITAMA1] 11 [SAITAMA]
3      0        0      2 3 [KANTO] 5 [+20MAN] 27 [SAITAMA1] 11 [SAITAMA]
4      0        0      3 3 [KANTO] 5 [+20MAN] 27 [SAITAMA1] 11 [SAITAMA]
```

## my operation

- I did the following operation:

```
# put NA in DK answer
jes2$PARTY1[jes2$PARTY1==5] <- NA
# reversed the order
jes2$PARTY1 <- car::recode(jes2$PARTY1,
                           "1=4; 2=3; 3=2; 4=1")
# change the class to factor
jes2$PARTY1 <- factor(jes2$PARTY1, ordered = TRUE, 
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3","4"))
# split the data to identify the wave 
jes2_wave2 <- subset(jes2, 
                     select = c("PARTY1", "ELECTION1", "CONGRESS1", "NOMATT1",
                                "INFLU1", "COMPLEX1", "NOCARE1"))
```

## the ERROR

Then I run fa() function in psych package

```
EFA_jes2_w5 <- fa(jes2_wave5, nfactors = 4, cor = "pol", rotate = "promax", scores = TRUE)
```

But I get an error like this

```
`.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) でerror: invalid 'row.names' length
```

How can I solve this?